# Pre-processing in remote sensing

Tags: remote-sensing, atmospheric-correction, reflectance, dark-object-subtraction

I have a bit of confusion on the pre-processing of remote sensed images. Do  atmospheric correction methods such as Dark Object Subtraction convert the DN into reflectance values? If not, it is considered an acceptable pre-processing to perform only a Dark Object Subtraction, or before is always required a radiometric calibration?